# with a google.com search, Uncaught TypeError: 湵敤楦敮d䊱 is not a function

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

In chrome canary, when do a google search, it gives an error in dev tools (with foreign chars) as see in screenshot. tried with latest version, and clearing all browsing data. error still persist. But, other websites works though. I could see the mentioned script originates from `https://www.google.com/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.s.en_US.LGvq-t0QqlE.O/m=sx,c,sb,cr,elog,jsa,r,hsm,j,p,pcc,csi/am=lKj_TwWDwIxAARMQ1AE/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oG9AUZL1sFIOK4Rk_2i9ay3OrZaNg`

canary: Version 40.0.2212.0 canary (64-bit)
OS: OSX 10.0.5

any malware or a bug?

ps: I tried few titles for this qn, but it all got rejected, based on SO quality warning.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was receiving this same error. It was caused by an extension I was running (Postman - REST Client). Navigate to `chrome://extensions/`, disable all extensions and confirm the issue does not exist. Then, enable them one by one to find the issue.

Comment: well, I used Postman before, but it wasn't enabled. I removed ALL extension, cleaned private data, restarted, and tried. still same error. Finally, removed canary, installed fresh, it is fine now. thanks for guiding in this path